# import com.android.build.OutputFile error in react-native

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, react-native

First I run a new project

```
react-native init AwesomeProject --version 0.58.6
```

(0.59.1 has a bug, but I test this problrm with it)

with `react-native run-android` I can run it.

In android studio when I sync it, I get an error:

**app/build.gradle**:

```
import com.android.build.OutputFile
```

> Error: Cannot resolve symbol 'build'

I use these versions:

```
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 27
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
}
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in android studio you can import only android part.

Goto:  File -> Open -> choose the project -> select folder with name android.

[Link given here](https://medium.com/@nevin_61019/creating-and-opening-your-react-native-project-in-android-studio-for-mac-db9b529cca28)

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Before running this command

```
react-native init AwesomeProject --version 0.58.6
```

Did you add the following to your System environmental variables ?

(1) **ANDROID_HOME** environment variable and

(2) **platform-tools** to Path

If not, make sure you add them. I have resolved this error by adding **all necessary paths to my system environment variables** as shown in the **Images** below and then I created a whole new project without any errors.

adding **ANDROID_HOME** environment variable:
[image: "adding ANDROID_HOME environment variable" image description here]

adding **platform-tools** to Path:
[image: "adding platform-tools to Path" image description here]

Also check out this link :

https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.60/enviroment-setup

Make sure that you have installed all necessary packages and added all necessary paths as mentioned in this link.